# Neo4j Cypher query to work on multiple relation

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

We have a graph where a user is related to some subject nodes of his/her interest and those subjects are connected to some questions by some relation. Its easy to get all the  questions of the interested subject of user by the below query.

```
match(u:user{name:'vartika'})<-[:userinteresttag]-(tag)-[:tagofquestion]->(q:question) return q.title
                    (user)
                  /        \
                 /          \
            (subject1)  (subject2)  (subject3)
             /  \             / 
            /    \           /   
       (ques1) (ques2) (ques3) (ques4)(ques5)
```

But now the issue is how to get the question of other than interested subjects of the particular user.  How to mould the query for getting question of non interest courses. ***( user and question nodes are not directly connected as can be seen in the graph)***

***I want to query for getting ques4 and ques5 which are not of userinteressubject as subject3 is not userinterestsubject ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of solution is to modify your database architecture and whenever question is asked by user to attach it to user directly and whenever you need also attach question to tag.
So you will have something like

```
match(u:user{name:'vartika'})-[:asked]->(q:question) return q.title
```

Another solution is something like

```
match(u:user{name:'vartika'})-[rel*1..3]->(q:question) return q.title
```

but it depends on your knowing the lengh of path between user and question

Edited:
Try this

```
match(u:user{name:'vartika'}) with u Match (q:question) where not (u)<-[:userinteresttag]-()-[:tagofquestion]->(q) return q
```

You will get all the question that not connected to user through tag

Comment: but sir its not related that the user have asked the question or not. Its like i wan to show the user some extra questions other than his/her related subjects. Hope you got me now

Comment: and the graph ex given above can make my question clear to you.  I have mentioned it in question also. thanku

Comment: why so i didnt got you.sorry sir. Can you please explain more clearly

Comment: i've eddited my answer with this you will get qeust4 and qeust5 for user vartika

Comment: Sir, it perfectlty worked for me. but still a lil bit confusion of using with. that i'll try to clear myself.